# I am new to C++ , need to know what is happening in line 10,12 and 16

Tags: c++, vector, stack

> I dont understand the part where it says `stack<T>`. Please help me understand it. Thank you!

```
 template <typename T>          

  class SetOfStacks
  {
   public:
       SetOfStacks(int c = 10) : capacity (c) {}
       ~SetOfStacks() {}
       void push(T val);
       void pop();
       T top();
       stack<T>& getLastStack();
       bool empty();
       vector<stack<T>> getStacks() const;
       int size();
       void popAt(int index);
  private:
        vector<stack<T>> stacks;
        int capacity;
  };
```

> LINE10

```
 stack<T>& getLastStack();
```

> LINE 12

```
 vector<stack<T>> getStacks() const;
```

> LINE 16

```
 vector<stack<T>> stacks;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to consult a beginners' tutorial or book. Stack Overflow is not a language tutorial site.

Comment: The second line of that code is an example of sloppy source layout, the naming of the class mixes (or misses) the concepts of equality and identity, and the first instruction (line 6) is dubious at best, besides other points. I doubt that this is good learning material for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a template instantiation.  There's too much to tell about templates to go on about it here.  I would suggest looking them up again in your book or searching the web.  Templates are both the greatest and worst part of C++.

Comment: I understand the template class part, but not where it says <stack<T>>. Is that an identifier of type stack ?

Comment: @SujithShivaprakash - vector is a template the same as stack is.  You're instantiating a vector of stacks of type T.  You really need to review templates.